# Has camera culling & crop to render region no effect on freestyle calculations?

Tags: rendering, freestyle, optimization

I'm rendering a large environment scene of 3.000.000 triangles with freestyle outlines at high output resolutions. The geometry is optimised, textures are basic and I've done what I could to avoid memory problems at freesyle rendering, so the scene renders fine, although takes a very long time.

Now I'm trying to render a camera view that shows a very small portion of the scene. I've tryed enabling camera culling in the render settings as well as render region & crop to render region in the hope that freestyle calculations will be faster but they seem to have no effect at all. Is there a way to tell freestyle not to compute the whole scene, only the portion visible to the camera?

Comment: Have you tried View Layer tab > Freestyle panel > Edge Detection > Culling? I have to confess on my rough and ready tests, that's only making about 20% difference...

Comment: No, I haven't noticed that checkbox. Looks like this is supposed to take care of exacly what I need. Unfortunately, like you mention, it probably only effects one stage of freestyle calculations so that the overall render time doesn't change much.